# facing difficulty to copy a object into object array

Tags: java

Hello I make a one hierarchy in which i have a super class called person and two sub class i.e Student and teacher now I want to take 5 student as a object, and take all information and and made one method to print some detail such as name now i write some code but the problem is that all object show same information..please help me in this and give me detail what i am doing wrong...thank in advance
my code is below:

```
public class L9t2 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        putdetails d=new putdetails();
        d.pdetails();
        d.printdetail();
    }
}
class putdetails{
     Student[] st=new Student[3];
    void pdetails(){
        String n,ln,a,r,d,pno,t,ci;
        double gpa; 
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int i;
        Student tst=new Student();
    // Student[] st=new Student[5];
    //   for( i=0;i<5;i++){
    //     st[i]=new Student();
    //   Student ch;
        for(i=0;i<3;i++ ){
            System.out.println("Put the Information of Student "+(i+1)+": ");
            System.out.print("Enter name: ");
            tst.setname(n=input.next());
            System.out.print("Enter last name: ");
            tst.setlname(ln=input.next());
            System.out.print("Enter address: ");
            tst.setaddress(a=input.nextLine());
            System.out.print("Enter roll no: ");
            tst.setrollno(r=input.nextLine());
            System.out.print("Enter GPA: ");
            tst.setgpa(gpa=input.nextDouble());

            st[i]=tst;

        /* System.out.println(ch.getname());
            System.out.println(tst.getname());*/
        }

    }
    void printdetail(){
      for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
            System.out.println("Name of "+(1)+"Student: "+st[i].getname());
        }   
    }
}
class person{
    private String name,address,l_name;
    void setname(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }
    void setaddress(String address){
        this.address=address;
    }
    void setlname(String l_name){
        this.l_name=l_name;
    }
    String getname(){
        return name;
    }
    String getlname(){
        return l_name;
    }
}
class Student extends person{
    private String rollno;
    private double gpa;
    void setrollno(String rollno){
        this.rollno=rollno;
    }
    void setgpa(double gpa){
        this.gpa=gpa;
    }
    String getrollno(){
        return rollno;
    } 
}
class Teacher extends person{
    private String degree,pno;
    void getdegree(String degree){
        this.degree=degree;

    }
    void getpno(String pno){
        this.pno=pno;
    }
} 
class Course{
    private String title,CourseID;
    void settitle(String title){
        this.title=title;
    }
    void setcourseid(String CourseID){
        this.CourseID=CourseID;
    }
    String gettitle(){
        return title;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hint: `new Student()` create a new "blank" one, and if you have two students you need two, not a *recycled* one

Comment: To make the hint even warmer, this where did you write the line: `Student tst=new Student();` - how many student objects you're actually creating ?

Comment: I see some naming issues in your code, it would be a good idea for you to look at [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: Regarding your question, it looks like you started writing correct code but commented it out. Take a look at the difference between `for( i=0;i<5;i++){
st[i]=new Student();` and what you are currently doing.